# How to use single editor window with tab views during source code editing?

Tags: macos, xcode

I'm working in a makefile based project (non-Xcode project) with lots of source files. When I double click a source file, it opens in a new window under Xcode.

Its impossible for me to keep track of the open source code windows because the windows are scattered around. Some windows are minimized in the launcher bar, and some are just hidden somewhere. And ALT+TAB does not enumerate all the open windows.

How do I instruct Xcode to use one window, and add the source file's view as a tab to that window?

(Sorry to ask. Turning knobs in preferences did not work, and I got nothing but tab view tutorials when I went searching).

Answer (score 1):

You can switch between windows of a same application with Cmd-` (Command backtick) .

On the other hand, you could View / Navigators / Show Project Navigator and drag/drop files onto the Project Navigador (Only create references). You also View / Show tab bar configure XCode to open file in new tab with double-click in Navigator.

Finally, I have Mission Control configured so that when moving to the left lower corner it shows me all windows from a same application.

Comment: Thanks Erny. So there is no way to use Xcode as a tabbed editor, like Visual Studio, Notepad++, etc? I *really* dislike Macs when it comes to all the stupid secret knocks, like Command-` and mouse movements through mission control.